# Recoding multiple numeric variables in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, recode, across

Can someone check what mistake I am doing? All my variables are Likert scale from 1 (extremely agree) and 7 (extremely disagree). Now in regression, these give negative relation with my increasing dependent variable. Therefore I wanted to change the order of the values in data. I want to change all these variable recoded from 1-7 to 7-1. I tried the following code

```
Newdata <- TPBdata %>% 
  mutate_at(c("V5","V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11",
              "V12", "V13", "V15", "V15", "V15_b", "V15_a",
              "V15_eco", "V18", "V19", "V20", "V21", "V24", "V26", "V25", "V22",
              funs(recode(., 7 == 1, 6 == 2, 5 == 3, 4 == 4, 3 == 5, 2 == 6, 1== 7, .default = NaN))))
```

I have tried with '7' = 1 also without quotes 7 = 1,

The error is

> Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()`
>   object, not a list Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error
>   occurred.

Comment: yes it keeps giving the error:: Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `dplyr`, I propose a `dplyr` solution. Also, since all the variables you inserted are in a Likert scale between 1 and 7, you can just apply to all the variables you want (indicated by the vector `all_your_vars`) the difference between 8 and their value - `NaN` will remain `NaN`.

```
TPBdata %>% 
  mutate(across(all_your_vars, ~ 8 - .x))
```

Example

```
set.seed(42)
TPBdata <- data.frame(
  V5 = sample(c(1:7, NaN), 5, replace = TRUE),
  V6 = sample(c(1:7, NaN), 5, replace = TRUE)
)
#   V5  V6
# 1  1   4
# 2  5   2
# 3  1   2
# 4  1   1
# 5  2 NaN

all_your_vars <- c("V5", "V6")
TPBdata %>% 
  mutate(across(all_your_vars, ~ 8 - .x))
#   V5  V6
# 1  7   4
# 2  3   6
# 3  7   6
# 4  7   7
# 5  6 NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @Ric S but I get that error: Error in across(c("V5_Regularly", "V6_Strange", "V7_routine", "V8_difficult",  : 
  could not find function "across"

Comment: `across` is a function added in `dplyr` 1.0.0, you need to update the package. If you, by any chance, cannot do that, use instead `TPBdata %>% mutate_at(all_your_vars, ~ 8-.x)`

Comment: Nice to hear that! :)   Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer if you found that helpful!

Comment: I am using R studio, maybe that is also part of the problem as most of the packages are installed under some warnings in this. Thank you for your help. Smart strategy indeed. couldn't think of it ever!!

Comment: Can I ask the function of .x? what does that do in the code? @Ric S

Comment: `.x` refers to the variables you input in the `across` statement *one by one*. So `mutate` applies the function of doing 8-variable one variable at a time